# Abbreviation in Orange's contingency table

Tags: orange

What do the scores `ARI` and `AMI` mean in Orange's contingency table?

[image]

Comment: Love your handwriting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARI stands for [adjusted Rand index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index) and AMI stands for [adjusted mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjusted_mutual_information).

They are metrics for clustering.

Remark:

- ARI might take negative values.
- The AMI takes a value of 1 when the two partitions are identical and 0 when the MI between two partitions equals the value expected due to chance alone.